# Does not getting data from rest Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, angular6

I'm trying to get data from rest api as follows,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-broker-ui',
  templateUrl: './broker-ui.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./broker-ui.component.css']
})
export class BrokerUIComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.load_broker_list();
  }

  load_broker_list(){
   return this._http.get("http://localhost:8080/broker/all")
                     .subscribe(
                      (data:any[]) => {
                       console.log(data);
                      }
                     )

  }

}
```

But it doesn't console.log the data, here are sample data

```
[ 
  { id: 1, username: "AAA" }, 
  { id: 2, username: "BBB" }, 
  { id: 3, username: "CCC" }, 
  { id: 4, username: "DDD" }, 
  { id: 5, username: "EEE" } 
]
```

This is the error i'm getting,

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BrokerUIComponent ->
>   HttpClient]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BrokerUIComponent ->
>   HttpClient]: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpClient` class is not found in the DI. You need to add `HttpClientModule` into your `AppModule`'s imports.

**Example**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      ...
      HttpClientModule
      ...
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using any HTTP service into your application you need to import  HttpClientModule to app-module.ts (main module), Like this -

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
     HttpClientModule
     // OtersModules
      ...
   ]
})
export class AppModule { 
 }
```